# Delete function not working for Active Storage image in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-admin, rails-activestorage

I’m trying to create a delete function for images that has been uploaded via active storage in my rails app.

I’m using devise for sign up, wicked wizard for multi step and cancancan for authorization. I'm also using rails admin.

But I get this error, and I can’t figure out how to make it work. I can see it has something to do with the routes, but i don't understand what the problem is and how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: uninitialized constant RegistrationsController]

**my form**

```
<%= form_for @user, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>

<% if @user.clinic_images.attached? %>

<% @user.clinic_images.each do |image| %>

<%= image_tag(image.variant(resize: "100x100")) %>
<%= link_to ‘Delete this image’, delete_image_attachment_registration_url(image.signed_id),

method: :delete,

data: { confirm: ‘Are you sure?’ } %>

<% end %>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users, controllers: {:registrations => "users/registrations"}
  resources :registration_steps
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'pages#index' 
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'team', to: 'pages#team'
  get 'faqs', to: 'pages#faqs'
  get 'faqspractitioners', to: 'pages#faqspractitioners'
  get 'faqsusers', to: 'pages#faqsusers'
  get 'login', to: 'pages#login'
  get 'signup', to: 'pages#signup'
  get 'search', to: 'pages#search'



  devise_scope :users do 
    resources :registrations do

      member do

        delete :delete_image_attachment

        end

    end
  end

end
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
  # frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def delete_image_attachment

    @image = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:id])

    @image.purge_later

    redirect_to root_path

    end


  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

 protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.



def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  registration_steps_path
 end


 def after_update_path_for(resource)

  registration_steps_path

end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end




end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def current_step?(step_key) current_step == step_key end

    enum gender: { Mand: 0, Kvinde: 1 }

    def self.genders_for_select
    genders.keys.map{ |x| [x.humanize, x] }
    end

    has_one_attached :clinic_logo

    has_one_attached :practitioner_image
    has_many_attached :clinic_images


    # Note that implicit association has a plural form in this case
    scope :with_eager_loaded_images, -> { eager_load(images_attachments: :blob) }

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

         after_create :send_admin_mail
         def send_admin_mail
           UserMailer.send_welcome_email(self).deliver_later
         end


end
```

Comment: when does this error occur? on form submit? on delete click? also you have set route for registration wrong, it should be `resources :registrations`

Comment: It happens on delete click. I'll try and correct resources :registration to resources :registrations when I get back home later, and see if it makes it work.

Comment: I've changed my route resources to

  resources :registrations do
    member do
      delete :delete_image_attachment
    end
  end
But I still get the uninitialized constant RegistrationsController error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your route resources wrong.

```
devise_scope :user do 
  scope module: :users do
    resources :registrations do
      member do
        delete :delete_image_attachment
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can read more about it here: https://rubyinrails.com/2019/04/16/rails-routes-difference-between-resource-and-resources/

Comment: I've changed my route resources to

resources :registrations do
but I still get the uninitialized constant RegistrationsController error

Comment: can you update your question with updated code and screenshot of error?

Comment: I've updated my question with the updated code and screenshot of the error.

Comment: registrations_controllers.rb should be registrations_controller.rb

Comment: it was a typo in my question, it has now been corrected

Comment: hm. please add definition of your controller to post

Comment: Do you mean the whole registrations_controller.rb, and not just a part of it?

Comment: it has now been added :-)

Comment: I've also added my user.rb file. I'm also using rails admin, don't know if the issue could be related to that.

Comment: `class Users::RegistrationsController` so that means file is in app/controllers/users/ folder and route should also be atleast under `users` namespace. like:
`namespace :user do
    resources: :registrations ....
end`

Comment: I've changed the route, I don't now if I have done it correctly, but now I'm getting another error. Please look at the updated question.

Comment: try this instead of `namespace :user do` :  `devise_scope :user do`

Comment: When I use devise_scope instead of namespace I get the Routing Error again, 'uninitialized constant RegistrationsController'

Comment: can you post your repository somewhere? this looks like problem that can be solved if I can see whole project

Comment: I cant make it run on my local. But you should have in routes `devise_scope :user` not `devise_scope :users`

Comment: I've tried to push the project to github again. Even if I change devise_scope :users to devise_scope :user I get the same uninitialized constant RegistrationsController routing error

Comment: its not like there is somehting wrong with your project at github, I dont have mysql setup, thats why it doesnt work on my local. anyway, my updated answer

Comment: Perfect it worked, thank you so much, appreciate it a lot :-)